# Disable product url without category path (SEO)

Tags: url, seo, category-tree, product-urls

When I set the option Use Categories Path for Product URLs to Yes, the product-URL changes to the one with categories path. Thats what I need.

But in that case the product is also availible trough domain.com/producturl.

How can I disable that?

This so that a product only got 1 URL, the URL with categories path.

Comment: If a product will assign at multiple categories then how you will change?

Comment: @AmitBera I guess in that case it should be displayed twice, but with a canonical. So that you will receive both benefits for SEO. But currently all products are displayed right trough domain.com/producturl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Category Path Yes / No which you want. then go to Database and open the table core_url_rewrite. delete the product url OR Run this query ( DELETE FROM `core_url_rewrite` WHERE `id_path` like %product/% ). Login to Admin Panel of your store and Re-index for Products.

Set the Redirection for old url which are index by google.