# Disable Product URL without Category Path

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, seo

My website I only use category URLs, I want to disable/redirect direct product link to link with category

i.e

```
example.com/catname/productname
example.com/productname [want to disable this]
```

I have set the SEO settings correctly for this:

Use Categories Path for Product URLs -> Yes

Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed -> Yes

Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories -> Yes

Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products -> No

We want to disable direct product access URL or redirect them with category URL.

Rewrite example.com/productname ---> example.com/catname/productname

**Or**

Disable this redirect: example.com/productname

I referred this but it's not working in my case.
[Ref Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109049/disable-product-url-without-category-path-seo)

Comment: @Hitesh doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Hitesh that is actually like the exact opposite of what the poster wanted...

Comment: @Hitesh what you suggested is exactly opposite.

Comment: @Sona check this answer if it help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/194552/55928 OR check this extension also https://github.com/wrglbr/Mage_DisabledProductsRedirect